# C# // GetResponseAsync() // NetworkCredential // .htaccess on a Windows 10 IoT Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: .htaccess, http, httpwebrequest

the code tries to download text from a php script via a http request. Since the code should run on a Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT I have to use GetResponseAsync(). It works fine if I use it without the credentials (Http source is public then). When I add the NetworkCredential stuff I get the exception you see in the picture.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEeQn.jpg)
In the end I want to be able to load data from a http website that is protected via .htaccess. I hope anyone has some experience with this!

```
namespace HttpGetBeisp1Hta {

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void ClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            await HoleDaten();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            textBlock.Text = ex.ToString();
        }

    }
    private async Task HoleDaten() {

            NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("user", "pw");
            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri("https://..'my secret uri'../getSave.php"), "Basic", myCred);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://..'my secret uri'../getSave.php");
            request.Credentials = myCache;


            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            textBlock.Text = responseFromServer;

    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it out!

I modified the header manually. The username and pw needs to be added in base64. Use a converter and feed it with "Hans:Mueller" gets you:

```
private async Task HoleDaten() {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https:// ... ll.php");                
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic SGFuczpNdWVsbGVy";
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            textBlock.Text = responseFromServer;

    }
```